# Vue.js doesnt re-render dom when variable changes onUploadProgress

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have following problem. In my app users are able to upload images. I upload images with axios. To have a better user experience i want to make a loadingbar.

Looks like this:

```
 <div class="loadingbox" :style="{width: loadbar + '%'}"></div>
```

My data looks like this:

```
  data() {
    return {
      loadbar: 0
    };
  },
```

Axios provides the function `onUploadProgress` so my idea was to update the lenght of the div with it:

```
 onUploadProgress(e) {
          let step = 100 / e.total;
          this.loadbar = e.loaded * step;
          console.log(this.loadbar);
        },
```

My console output is :

```
0
20.334
89.32
100
```

But my width of the div doesnt change at all. If i put for example `loadbar: 50` then i can see 50% of the bar.

Any idea why vue.js doesnt detect the changes?

Udated:

I emulated it in `created()`

```
created() {
    let loaded = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
      loaded += 1000;
      let total = 30000;
      let step = 100 / total;
      this.loadbar = loaded * step;
    }, 1000);
}
```

It works totally fine at this case.

Comment: Can you emulate a progress (just one change) using setTimeout? A result would be the same?

Comment: @Anatoly i have updated the question. i have emulated it and it works

Comment: Try to wrap setting this.loadbar into this.$nextTick: `this.$nextTick(() => { this.loadbar = e.loaded * step;
          console.log(this.loadbar); })`

Comment: "Vue performs DOM updates asynchronously. Whenever a data change is observed, it will open a queue and buffer all the data changes that happen in the same event loop." Can you have the value of loadbar printed in template and see if it is updating. If not, you can make use of nextTick.

Comment: @Himanshu no i cant see it in the template aswell, i try it with nexttick

Comment: @Anatoly thank you, but i have founded the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem. `this` is not binded to the vue instance, its binded to the uploadprogress itself. I declared a variable `self` and binded it to my vue instance:

```
let self = this;
 axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "/api/upload/image/profile_image",
        data: formData,
        onUploadProgress(e) {
          let step = 100 / e.total;
          self.loadbar = e.loaded * step;
        },
        ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the only issue is that the `div` is empty. Here is a testing demo that I tried:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      loadbar: 0
    };
  },
  mounted(){
    let that = this;
    const interval = setInterval(function() {
      that.loadbar += 20;
      console.log(that.loadbar)
      if(that.loadbar === 100)
           clearInterval(interval);
    }, 5000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div 
      class="loadingbox" 
      style="background-color:red;"
      :style="{width: loadbar + '%'}"
    >loading...</div>
</div>
```